# I cant use the function Ungroup in Power apps

Tags: powerapps

As you can see in the image below, I am doing a correct call of the formula "Ungroup()". The error says: A column named "NroVale" already exists.
It is worth mentioning that without the ungroup() sentence the code works correctly. [image]

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Solved. The problem was that I was trying to merge two columns with identical column names. Once I changed that it worked.